# Twilio Error: 13214 - Dial: Invalid callerId value

Tags: android, node.js, twilio

We are using Twilio voice quickstart server example in node, Here's [link](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-node/) and Client-side Application for Android. When placing call getting "Invalid callerId" error on the server side.

> We are using verified Twilio number.

Comment: In the quickstart application there is a `callerNumber` that should be updated to your Twilio number, it is "1234567890" by default. Did you change this? https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-node/blob/master/src/server.js#L9

Answer (score 1):

This error i also found and following solution worked for me

Check your Twilio call params (Accesstoken,To and Clientname)

Above three param must not contains any special chars and it must contains only letters, numbers, or underscore. So if you are passing any space or + or any thing other then underscore then it will give this error.

I get to know from debugger of twilio site.

https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger?quickDate=24